# iOS UIPickerView how to get the selected row outside the delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I know the UIPickerView has this method:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
      didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

But inside this method, I want to get the selected row of other components. How on Earth can I do that?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/selectedRowInComponent:

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can get selected row number anywhere by using [selectedRowInComponent](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/selectedRowInComponent%3a) method of `UIPickerView`.

Such like

```
NSString *YourselectedTitle = [self.yourArrayName objectAtIndex:[self.yourPickerName selectedRowInComponent:0]];
NSLog(@"%@", YourselectedTitle);
```

Comment: it works. But I don't understand: I have typed "row0 = [self.picker sel" and no suggestion appeared! only a "select" method that has nothing to do with the UIPickerView; it there something wrong with my Xcode?

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru - put your code here i do work with above code it working very well for me  :)

Comment: it works! the problem is another: while I was typing "sel" XCode should have shown me the suggestion "selectedRowInComponent", but it didn't!

Comment: if there is an error in a previous line or in the line preceding your typing "sel" xcode will not give suggestions (it seems.) You need to be "caught up" to that point before it will give suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

Old question but if someone like me is working with Swift 2.0 now the answer is

```
let row = self.myPicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)
let value = myArray[row]
```

I wrote 0 to component value because my picker has only one component, but it could have more than one such as datepicker with Date and Time

You can even use this method outside the function that you were talking about if you keep an outlet of your pickerview